# Como configurar um campo existente para auto-incremento?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de definir o campo `id` já criado como auto-incremento, porque eu criei a tabela e não coloquei essa opção para ele, como poderia fazer isto?

Comment: Pode colocar na sua pergunta a sentença de criação da tabela?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para alteração basta usar os seguintes comando:

Para SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE <TABELA>
ALTER COLUMN <Nome_Coluna> Identity (1,1) // caso for sql server
```

Para MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE <TABELA>
MODIFY COLUMN <Nome_Coluna> AUTO_INCREMENT // caso for My SQL
```

Comment: Haha obrigada. Mas pena que você demorou para responder porque eu apaguei a tabela e fiz outra com o identity. Mas vou testar sim.

Comment: É sql server mas o nome da coluna é id...Como ficaria isso?Oo ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ID Identity (1,1) // caso for sql server?

Comment: Isso, porém vc precisa substituir o TABLE pelo nome da sua tabela... Disponha e se este campo for chave primária adicionar PRIMARY KEY ao final.